# How can I use html output instead of png from my R script on Knowage R webservice?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, ggsave

Using Knowage, its stated that the output can either be an or html. I have tried unsuccessfully to use the html output but it keeps coming back as R error on the application, I have used different methods where it creates the html file in the directory but i need it displayed in the application like the images below. can i get help with this please?

[image]

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfuQH.png)